# Crystal Report 13 and PHP integration error

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I want to integrate php and crystal report, im using CI and sql server database and running IIS. I have installed the 32 bit runtime because im running 32 bit version of php 7.0 in 64 bit windows server 2012. i have enabled 32 bit application IIS, and now im stuck in this error:

**An uncaught Exception was encountered**
Type: com_exception

Message: **Source**: Unknown

**Description**: Unknown

Here is my construct on my crystalreport.php

```
public function __construct($params){
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $this->_file = $params['file'];
    $this->_orientation = isset($params['orientation']) ? $params['orientation'] : "D";
    //echo $this->_path.$params['modul'].'/'.$this->_file.".rpt";exit;
    $this->_Object= new COM('CrystalReports13.ObjectFactory.1') or die ("Could not initialise Object.");

    $this->_App = $this->_Object->CreateObject('CrystalRuntime.Application.13') ;
    $this->_Report =  $this->_App->OpenReport($this->_path.$params['modul'].'/'.$this->_file.".rpt", 1);
    $this->_Report->EnableParameterPrompting = 0;
    $this->_config['server'] = $CI->db->hostname;
    $this->_config['database'] = $CI->db->database;
    $this->_config['uid'] = $CI->db->username;
    $this->_config['pass'] = $CI->db->password;

}
```

The error pointed at the **CreateObject();**

Comment: what was the exception? if it doesn't display put a try catch block around everything and catch `\Exception`

Comment: the rest of the error message is the line number of the errors, which is
`$this->_App = $this->_Object->CreateObject('CrystalRuntime.Application.13') ;`